# Rewrite URL regex: different filenames to same URL structure

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

e.g. from

```
A: www.example.com/food.php
B: www.example.com/food2.php?type=bacon
C: www.example.com/food2.php?type=tomato
```

It's easy to get:

```
A: www.example.com/food
B: www.example.com/food2/bacon
C: www.example.com/food2/tomato
```

But how about getting the following from my original URL structure?

```
B: www.example.com/food/bacon
C: www.example.com/food/tomato
```

Do I need to keep the same filename to get the desired URLs or is there some regex to do it without causing problems?

I don't have much experience with regex, just simple rewrites from templates.

Comment: Does `www.example.com/food/tomato` still need to redirect to `food2.php`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - it'll need to pick up the content from there instead of food.php.

Comment: Do u want to change from `www.example.com/food2.php?type=bacon` to `www.example.com/food/bacon`?

Comment: Yes @Mr.kang - without causing any conflict with food.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^food/([^/]*)$ /food2.php?type=$1 [L]
```

This will leave you with the URLS:

`www.example.com/food/bacon`

`www.example.com/food/tomato`

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks - and this won't cause any conflict with /food.php (which will be rewritten to /food)? If not, I'll try it at the weekend.

Comment: No, this will not conflict with that as that is not making use of $1 variables.

Comment: Had time to test this yet @AlexHarford? Should work without issue.

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite config should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.example.com)$
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "\/food"
RewriteRule "(food)\/([a-z]+)$" "$12\.php\?type=$2"
```

Please refer to [mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for more details

Please don't be confused with "$12" backreference -- mod_rewrite only offers one-digit references from $1 to $9 (and $0 for a whole matched string), hence it is reference to first *(group)* followed with "2".

Comment: I get "/food/bacon.php" not found on the server when I try this (inputting the URL without the .php extension), but thickguru's code worked. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this? I used vim's substitution command.

[image]

[image]

Comment: /food.php needs to be /food also - I know how to do a sitewide file extension removal, but am hoping B & C can be rewritten to /food/ without causing a  conflict with the rewritten A.

Comment: @AlexHarford I don't konw about mod-rewrite. So i used vim. I hope it helps.